# Bootstrap and index.php

Tags: zend-framework

Could anybody tell me please what is the difference between **Bootstrap.php** and **index.php** files in zend framework ?

Answer (score 3):

In `index.php` you only set up the `Zend_Application` to run. This means `include_path`s, `require_once`s, `application.ini` etc.

In `Bootstrap.php` you are already "inside" the running application. This is the place to set up more specific resources (database, cache, plugins, ...).

Answer (score 1):

`index.php` is used to set paths and configure your environment.

`Bootstrap.php` is used to load application specific things like database, locale or other things.